# How add angular/material for ngx-admin

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-admin

I'm working with `ngx-admin` and it is familiar with `Nebular` Theme. But I want to add `angular/material` for it. I used `lazyloading` for this project.
I tried install material for this by `npm i @angular-materials/ngx-admin` command. but it not success. I have a component named `profile`.

**profile.component.html**

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-toolbar class="toolbar">
            <mat-card-title>Contact List</mat-card-title>
            <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
            <mat-icon (click)="addContact()">add</mat-icon>
        </mat-toolbar>
    </mat-card-header>
</mat-card>
```

**profile.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
MatDialogModule,
MatToolbarModule,
MatIconModule,
MatCardModule
} from '@angular/material';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [ProfileComponent],
imports: [
    CommonModule,

    MatDialogModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatToolbarModule
]
})
export class ProfileModule {}
```

I want to integrate angular/material with this. Then what I should do for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import this theme into your styles.css file. It will get you material theme

```
  @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```